# Cannot get the latest value of context in useEffect

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use a context value as a initial state for a consuming component. I am subscribe to the state via `useEffect` but i am not getting the latest values.

i can avoid doing all these unnecessary things using `componentWillMount`within my provider but its going to be deprecated soon..

This is my context provider when mounted i am checking whether a token session is valid and changes the state accordingly which is being consume by some components.

```
    state = {
        userData: [],
        isAuthenticated: false,
        _defaultLogin: this._defaultLogin,
        _setToken: this._setToken,
        loginPopUp: false
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        const { history } = this.props;
        if(!this._validSession()){   
            this.setState({
                loginPopUp: true,
                isAuthenticated: false
            })
        } else {
            try {
                const userData = this._getUserData();
                this.setState({
                    userData,
                    isAuthenticated: true
                })
            } catch (err) {
                this._logOut();
                history.push('/')
            }
        }
    }
```

In one of the consuming component i want to know if some context values was updated and use the latest value.

```
    const authService = useContext(AuthServiceContext) // use the context

    const [modalShow, setModalShow] = useState(authService.loginPopUp) // use the context loginpopup value as initial state which is false by default

    useEffect(() => {
        setModalShow(authService.loginPopUp) // set the modal according to the value
    }, authService.loginPopUp) // when provider changes state i am expecting to get the new value
```

I expect for the setModalShow() to use the latest value of `authService.loginPopUp` context but it is always false

Comment: first: `useEffect` expects dependencies as an array. You are passing boolean primitive value.

Comment: second: I don't follow what you want to achieve. You may just refer to `authService.loginPopup` in your component without any extra `useState + useEffect` and component will be re-rendered on each context's update with most recent context data.

Comment: You should try `[authService.loginPopUp]`